# Does Huawei E220 modem work on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 11.10, 12.10, usb-modem, huawei

In order to make the above dongle work on my current version of Ubuntu 11.10, I have to run

```
sudo usb_modeswitch -v 0x12d1 -p 1003 -V 0x12d1 -P 1003 -R
```

and remove the modem and connect again.

Have anyone tried the E220 on the new Ubuntu 12.10? Does it work without such problems?

Comment: Just installed 12.04 LTS and the modem works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is modem is supported in Ubuntu 12.10, according to Wikipedia. Please visit this link, which could be helpful for you.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huawei_E220